# Javascript string translation for wordpress

Tags: javascript, wordpress, wpml

I am using campaign monitor plugin which is not WPML ready, i need to translate error messages in javascript file. This is the chunk of code in app.js file

```
function cmApp_validateForm()
{

    var signupContainerElem=jQuery("#cmApp_signupContainer");

    var errorElem = jQuery("#cmApp_emailError");
    var errorElemDOB = jQuery("#cmApp_dobError");
    var formElem = signupContainerElem.find("form");
    var processingMsgElem = signupContainerElem.find("div.cmApp_processingMsg");
    var successMsgElem = signupContainerElem.find("div.cmApp_successMsg");


    var errorMsgAr=[];
    var errorFieldSelectorAr=[];

    var errorMsg="";

    formElem.hide();
    errorElem.html("").hide();
    errorElemDOB.html("").hide();
    successMsgElem.hide();

    cmApp_showProcessing();

    signupContainerElem.find("input,select").css("outline","none");

    // validate the email field. make sure it is not empty and that it is valid. if invalid, add to the error array and outline the field in red
    var email = jQuery("#cmApp_signupEmail").val();

    if (email.length < 1) {
        errorMsg = "Geef een geldig e-mailadres in";
        errorMsgAr[errorMsgAr.length]="Please provide correct email";
        jQuery("#cmApp_signupEmail").focus().css("border" , "2px solid #D95350");
    }
    else {
        if (!cmApp_validateEmail(email)) {
            errorMsgAr[errorMsgAr.length]="This is an invalid email";
            errorFieldSelectorAr[errorFieldSelectorAr.length]="#cmApp_signupEmail";
            jQuery("#cmApp_signupEmail").focus().css("border","2px solid #D95350");
        }
    },
```

I tried to translate using this example to make it available in sting translation.

```
// Register the script
wp_register_script( 'some_handle', 'path/to/myscript.js' );

// Localize the script with new data
$translation_array = array(
    'some_string' => __( 'Some string to translate', 'plugin-domain' ),
    'a_value' => '10'
);
wp_localize_script( 'some_handle', 'object_name', $translation_array );

// Enqueued script with localized data.
wp_enqueue_script( 'some_handle' );
```

But i do not understand what should i fill in 'some handle' and what should be the objectname? Or is there any simple method to translate this?

Could anyone explain how can i translate these error text?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

**'some_handle'** is just the name you use to register your script through WordPress, can be whatever, just make sure the handle follows rules like no space, etc.

**'object_name'** is the JavaScript variable name that's going to be declared as the translation object.

e.g.

```
$translate_array['a'] = __('string_a');
```

If your object name is '`translation_obj`', you would be able to retrieve  `translation_obj.a` in your client-side JavaScript.

The translation is done by WordPress and its multi-lingual plugin that you choose. Read more on internationalization: https://codex.wordpress.org/I18n_for_WordPress_Developers.

Comment: I tried what you said, it's showing in the string translation but not translating the text :( Is there any external jquery or javascript function which can translate according to language?

Comment: No, the translation is not done automatically (we wish). You need to install multilingual plugins in which you need to do the string translations yourself. WPML https://wpml.org/ is such a multi-lingual plugin. But to be honest, I strongly recommend just writing your own custom code to handle translations if translations are minimal. Maybe just read off of a language string array file. WPML is very resource heavy and quite bloated in my opinion.